# Accomplishing "Business" transactions multi-tier architecture with physical separation

Tags: c#, wcf, transactions, n-tier-architecture

Given an application broken up like with the following layers/tiers

Application Layer, Business Layer, Data Tier (exposed to business through WCF, physically separated from App/Bussiness and Data), and Data. 
How would one go about accomplishing transactions started in the business tier but acting on the data tier?

Data Tier:

```
[DataContract]
public class Customer
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Order
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}

/*
    CRUD classes on both entities (I'm hoping this implementation does not matter on the data tier, as the transactions I hope to start on the business end and could potentially have different implementations on the data tier across different areas)
*/
```

Business:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Customer PurchasedBy { get; set; }
}

public class PlaceOrderService
{

    public void Execute(Order order)
    {

        try
        {
            // Begin Transaction
            // Call to data tier to create/get customer depending on if they are new or existing
            // Call to data tier to create order
            // Commit transaction
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Rollback transactions
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Take a look at [Distributed Transaction Coordinator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759136(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Would there be no way to implement the unit of work pattern in a scenario such as this?  I've only just started looking into it, so implementing it for the first time in a multi tier environment has me tripped up in figuring out where to get started.

Comment: I have never used it actually but I believe that's what it's for. It should work with WCF.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to design and manage your own logical transactions through a service.

Typically this means a process flow of:

1. Request start logical transaction from the Transaction service
2. Receive logical transaction ID for your transaction
3. All messages/calls in the process will have the transaction ID included and
   likely mean a segregated area in physical DB for uncommitted data
   while transaction is still in progress.
4. Once relevant calls have been made and data verified, request commit of logical transaction or request a rollback depending on the results of verification/validation.

I have seen this implemented in a messaging based system and it worked relatively well but does require some overhead to manage the logical transaction correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If the data tier is physically seperate and does not represent a business transaction facsade, then you have to roll your own compensating resource manager. If the data tiers is on the business facsade then you can create your SQL transaction and pass that into each data tier call so they can join the transaction.

In many cases the only transaction-ability we have at our disposal is the SQL Server database engine transaction. In a multi-database environment, utilising queues and other non-relational databases even this is not available. In which case you would need to craft a data reversal operation for each of the components of the transaction (i.e. a DELETE if you are intending an INSERT) in the various data storage architectures and use those to back out your failed transaction.